# Best way to get the lowest item in a list

Tags: c#, list, wpf-controls, min

Situation: I got 3 classes that work with each other.
1: Main (the GUI)
2: Compare (to compare the values)
3: CompareData (inherits the list values)

I want to take two values: a string and a double, and put them in a list. Of course there will be more than just one list item at the end. After the list got filled, I'd like to get the lowest double with it's string and put them in a label.

Here is what I've got so far:

Main:

```
public class GlobaleDaten //The second List: VglDaten is the one for my situation
{
    public static List<Daten> AlleDaten = new List<Daten>();
    public static List<Vgl> VglDaten = new List<Vgl>();
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  [...Some Code thats not relevant...]


//addListAb adds values in a ListBox and should also 
//place them into the list VglDaten

    public void addListAb()
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(Abzahlungsdarlehenrechner.zgName + " " + "[Abzahlungsdarlehen]" + " " +Abzahlungsdarlehenrechner.zmErg.ToString("0.00") + "€" + " " + Abzahlungsdarlehenrechner.zgErg.ToString("0.00") + "€");

        Vgl comp = new Vgl();
        comp.name = Abzahlungsdarlehenrechner.zgName;
        comp.gErg = Abzahlungsdarlehenrechner.zgErg;

        GlobaleDaten.VglDaten.Add(comp);
    }

//bVergleich should compare these values from the list 
//and show the lowest value in a label
    public void bVergleich_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox.Items.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte erst Einträge hinzufügen.");
        }
        else
        {
            VglRechner vglr = new VglRechner();
            vglr.Compare();

            lVergleich.Content = VglRechner.aErg + " " + "€";
        }
    }
```

CompareData:

```
//Only used for storing the values
public class Vgl : Window
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double gErg { get; set; }
}
```

Compare:

```
public class VglRechner
{

    public static string aName;
    public static double aErg;

    public void Compare(Vgl comp)
    {

   //I'm not sure if this is the right way to compare the values
   //correct me if I'm wrong please :)
        double low = GlobaleDaten.VglDaten.Min(c => comp.gErg);

        aErg = low;
        aName = comp.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Enumerable.Min` is the right way to get the lowest value but you won't get the `string` which belonged to that value in this way, so the `Vgl` instance.

You could use this approach:

```
Vgl lowestItem = GlobaleDaten.VglDaten.OrderBy(c => c.gErg).First();
aErg   = lowestItem.gErg;
aName  = lowestItem.name;
```

Comment: The comparing works perfectly, thank you :) But I've got another question: When I want to set the label to the value of aErg and aName it is still 0. Eventhough VglRechner.aErg is correct, isn't it?

Comment: To my comment: Had nothing to do with your or my code. There was an wrong property for the label, sorry for confusion you :)